# How to get clusters location in tabletop_object_detector?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I used tabletop_object_detector correctly in my own node and call the segmentation service and get the cluster size correctly. Now I need to get the location in XYZ of the segmented objects (clusters) but I don't know how.

Note: I use the segmentation node only without recognition facility.

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189660/how-to-get-clusters-location-in-tabletop_object_detector-?/) by [Haitham El-Hussieny](https://answers.ros.org/users/19972/haitham-el-hussieny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The segmentation service just returns the points in the cluster.  If you want a representative 'location' for the clusters, you might find the bounding box and use that.  This service, for instance, can give you a bounding box based on 2-D PCA (z-axis is up, like you probably want on a table).  (You want the non-3d version for table objects.)

https://github.com/ros-interactive-manipulation/object_manipulation/blob/groovy-devel/object_manipulator/scripts/cluster_bounding_box_finder_server.py

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0